# Communicate with child process multiple times

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make some communications with mongo shell. Unfortunately I receive bytes only the first time (after first `show dbs\n`), and after that the second `show dbs\n` call hasn't made. Moreover I don't see the long line `------...` (I marked It), some infinite loop is observed (the program does not finish).

What am I doing wrong? I did not find such cases on the Internet when people make communications with child processes multiple times. All such examples is all about send via `in` once and read via `out` once, but not multiple times.

```
fn main() -> Result<(), failure::Error> {
   let mut mongod = Command::new("mongo")
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("mongo was not started");


    let mut inp = mongod.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();
    let r = inp.write_all(b"show dbs\n")?;
    let r = inp.flush()?;

    let mut reader = BufReader::new(mongod.stdout.take().unwrap());

    let mut s = String::new();
    while let Ok(n) = reader.read_line(&mut s) {
        println!("{:?}", n);
    }

    //  !don't see it!
    println!("{}", "-------------------------------------------");
    let r = inp.write_all(b"show dbs\n")?;
    let r = inp.flush()?;

    while let Ok(n) = reader.read_line(&mut s) {
        println!("{:?}", n);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you run `echo "show dbs" | mongo` in a shell?